# Making a element drop down and bounce without going past its static position

Tags: html, css, css-animations

im trying to make a CSS animation with key frames where a div drops down and does bounces once before being stationary

I have managed to get this so far

```
 @keyframes bounce{
  0%{
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-2000px) rotate(-45deg);
   }
  60%{
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg);
    }
  80%{
    transform: translateY(-10px) rotate(-45deg)
    }
  100%
  {
    transform: translateY(0) rotate(-45deg)
    }
}
```

It kind of bounces but it goes under its original position like elastic but i wanted a hard floor so it doesnt go under its original position. Here is my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/s42t6wua/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can consider scaling effect to obtain this:

```css
.pin {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 0;
  background: blue;
  position: absolute;
  transform: rotate(-45deg);
  transform-origin: bottom; /*don't forget this*/
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  margin: -20px 0 0 -20px;
  animation-name: bounce;
  animation-fill-mode: both;
  animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    transform: translateY(-2000px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform:scaleY(0.6) translateY(30px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  100% {
    transform:  scaleY(1) translateY(0) rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class='pin'></div>
```

Comment: oh wow that is very cool ,its almost like it gets squished at the bottom

Comment: @RachelDockter yes, it's not like you wanted? it's like a ball that hit the ground

Answer (score 1):

Seems like just fiddling with your numbers a bit does the job.

```
  60% {
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px) rotate(-45deg);
  }
  80% {
    transform: translateY(-20px) rotate(-45deg)
  }
```

Here are some demos with the baseline marked.

[Original](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/o9tu2bpj/)
[Updated](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/karpc15s/5)

Comment: Thanks its abit blocky but it bounces, :D